# Google Drive’s “Add shortcut to Drive” creates symlink to itself

Tags: mac, google-drive-for-desktop

In my Google Drive, I have a folder which is shared from another Google Drive. On the web, the folder shows up under *Shared with me*.

I would like to add this folder to My Drive, so that it will sync to the Macs where I have Google Drive Desktop installed. I use mirroring mode, not streaming mode, on all my machines.

As far as I can tell, the ‘proper’ way to do this is to add a shortcut to *My Drive* (or a subfolder), and indeed, if I do this, it works exactly as it should on the web: a shortcut shows up in *My Drive*, and double-clicking on it takes me to the actual folder in my shares.

On the desktop machines, the shortcut does get synced, but the file that is added in the Google Drive folder is a symlink whose target is just the location of the symlink itself (i.e., `/Users/me/Google Drive/Shared Folder Name`), which obviously doesn’t help.

I’ve tried adding and removing several different shortcuts a number of times, in different locations, but the result is the same every time: a self-targeting symlink.

I’ve found lots of people asking on various sites how to do this, but they all seem to either **a)** be from the Backup and Sync days and thus not relevant anymore, or **b)** only give answers to the effect that you just need to create a shortcut, which is exactly what doesn’t work for me.

So my questions are:

- Is it expected behaviour for a shortcut to a shared folder to be a symlink to itself?

  - If yes, is there some other way to actually sync a shared folder to Google Drive Desktop?
  - If no, what are some possible reasons for the behaviour I’m seeing and ways to fix it?